# Identify request handler for API Gateway endpoint using AWS web console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-application-load-balancer, amazon-elb

If i make a POST request to API gateway endpoint (configured to handle POST calls), by using AWS console how can i identify which AWS service (lambda/fargate/etc) is configured as request handler for that endpoint.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-basic-concept.html

suggest `For Integrations, choose Add integration.`
But how can i find handlers/integration for an existing endpoint.

I am only able to identify `Invoke URL` and lambda service used as authenticator. OR do i need to manually check each Application load balancer ?

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to add Integrate with ALB, you could select the HTTP in **Integration Request > Integration Type** and input the ALB DNS into **Endpoint URL**.

Check out this image: [Integration Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIOtX.png)

Comment: i don't want define or add a new Integration, i want to identify what is the integration type for an existing API.

Comment: @BharatPahalwani, if you're just trying to see what is currently configured, you should be able to click on the API -> Resources -> (find the resource path and method) -> Click on the Method (POST) ... then in the right panel click on the "Integration Request" ... that will show you the current API Integration.

Comment: @BharatPahalwani, if you've already done all that to get the invoke url, then yes: you need to go manually find the service that provides that url.